# TypeError: gitlab is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gitlab

I have a problem with my code TypeScript, am using the library of node gitlab, and have installed the package correctly, so much in @types as in node_modules, am trying to do a CRUD for gitlab, and just now I am fulfilling the backend with express. When the controller to do of gitlab and on having compiled to javascript, he throws error to me:
[image: Error throws]

and here is my code:

```
// Import only what we need from express
   import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express';
   import * as gitlab from "gitlab";

// Assign router to the express.Router() instance
   const router: Router = Router();
   const api = new gitlab({
     url: 'http://git.test.com/',
     token: 'asdasfgwsgsafa',
   });

   const users = api.users.all();

   router.get('/allUsers', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      res.send(users);
   });
 // The / here corresponds to the route that the gitLabController
 // is mounted on in the server.ts file.
 // In this case it's /gitlab
   router.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
// Reply with a hello world when no name param is provided
     res.send('Hello, World!');
   });

  router.get('/:name', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    // Extract the name from the request parameters
    res.send(`Hello, ${req.params.name}`);
  });

 // Export the express.Router() instance to be used by server.ts
 export const gitLabController: Router = router;
```

I hope that they could help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: try `import gitlab from "gitlab";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing all the modules from `gitlab`. You can do

```
import Gitlab from "gitlab";
```

Then,

```
const api = new Gitlab({
   url: 'http://git.test.com/',
   token: 'asdasfgwsgsafa'
});
```

Since, you are doing `import * as gitlab from "gitlab";` it does not get the `gitlab` module when you do `new gitlab`

With the way you have imported you need to do:

```
const api = new gitlab.Gitlab({
   url: 'http://git.test.com/',
   token: 'asdasfgwsgsafa'
});
```

For further reading you can refer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitlab)